# How do i store a string inside a node in a linked list? I am working on Visual Studio.

Tags: c

I am passing a dynamically allocated string from my `main.c` to a fucntion `addNode()` as a pointer `*str`.

I want to add this string to a field in the the node i created.

```
// Structure definitions
// Node in doubly-linked list

typedef struct DLN {
    struct DLN *prev;       // Pointer to previous list element
    struct DLN *next;       // Pointer to next list element
    char *word;
} DLNode;

// Actual doubly-linked list
typedef struct {
    DLNode *firstNode;  // Pointer to first node in list
    DLNode *lastNode;   // Pointer to last node in list
} DLList;

// Function prototypes

void addNode(DLList *list, char *str);  
void addNode(DLList *list, char *str) {

    DLNode *newNode;

    newNode = (DLNode*)malloc(sizeof(DLNode));

    if (newNode == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error:Could not allocate new node\n");
        exit(0);
    }


    //list is empty, add one node 
    if ((list->firstNode == NULL) && (list->lastNode == NULL)) {
        list->firstNode = newNode;
        list->lastNode = newNode;
        newNode->next=NULL;
         newNode->prev=NULL;

          //(newNode->word)=*str;

         //strncpy(newNode->word, , );???
    }
```

Comment: My C is a bit rusty, but wouldn't `newNode.word = str` be correct?

Comment: newNode->word = str ;  // I hope you already allocated the memory in main.

Comment: Big problem: you malloc() space for the node ... but you don't allocate any space for the string.  SUGGESTION: just make `word` a fixed size, e.g. `char word[80]`.  Or better, `#define WORD_LEN 80`, then declare `char word[WORD_LEN]`.  And use `strcpy()` to copy the string.

Comment: In my main program i am already dynamically allocating space for the string as it is read from the user. Inside the above function, all im trying to do is create a node and place this string inside it. Im not sure how to write the strncpy() function.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code simple declare word as a character array in DLNode. say char word[50].

```
char word[50]; // in your DLNode structure 
memset(newNode->word, '\0', sizeof(newNode->word)); // In addNode code
strcpy(newNode->word, str); // In addNode code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `str` is a valid C string and will not be freed anywhere else but in the node memory managing, then you can just do a simple assignment:

```
newNode->word = str;
```

But if `str` is accessed in *any* other way other than through the node, then allocate a new string and store its pointer in `newNode->word`:

```
newNode->word = (char*)malloc(strlen(str)+ 1);

if (newNode->word == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error:Could not allocate new string for node\n");
    exit(0);
}

strcpy(newNode->word, str); // newNode->word is large enough, so this is safe.
```

Then you can free the string when the node is freed, to keep things a bit tidier.

Comment: I tried your method but it doesn't work. I tried using the strncpy function as strncpy(newNode->word, &str, sizeof(str)); the debugger says " error reading characters" when i hover over the newNode->word part of the strncpy function

Comment: I tried it on [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/kt2PYF) and it works. Strange it isn't for you. Also, `str` is already a pointer; no need to get the pointer to the pointer.

Comment: Also also, `sizeof(str)` gets the size of the pointer (usually 4 or 8 bytes) and not the size of the string (that's what `strlen` is for).